# "setProperties" does not pass "attrs" as expected

Tags: ember.js

I have a wrapping component, which yields some other component in itself. (Think about form control group or a table cell component).

To make it as flexible as possible I pass `attrs` to the `hash` property. And all component will set `hash` on itself.

```
Ember.Component.reopen({
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    this.setProperties(this.get('hash'));
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/suvenijuxu/1/edit?html,js,output

It works fine with **Strings** but not with objects. In my-wrapper component `attrs.model.name` has the correct value (see the template), but after `attrs` is passed to the property `hash` and set by `setProperties` it is transformed to `MutStream`. (see console.log)

Why does this transformation happens? Is this the expected behavior?  Is my approach considered as an anti-pattern? Is there a workaround? What does `MutStream` or `MUTABLE_REFERENCE` mean?