# Wrapper Component for Form Controls

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking for a pattern to make a wrapper component for form controls.

**Its role:** wrap any kind of component, (handle error states, messages)

**Syntax:**

```
{{form-control-group type="my-input" label="Some fancy label:"}}
```

**templates/components/form-control-group.hbs**

```
{{#if hasError }}
  {{error}}
{{/if}}
{{label}}
{{component type}}
```

It works nice, as long as I don't need any attribute `for my-input` component. Usually it is not the case. Let's say I need pass the value. I could do

```
{{component type value=value}}
```

But as not that flexible as I wanted to have it. I will gonna use it with different form controls, ex.: select, checkbox etc. They all need different attributes. 
I also could prepare for this different attributes:

```
{{component type 
  value=value
  content=content
  contentPath=contentPath
  disabled=disabled
  checked=checked
  ...
}}
```

In this way it can be used only with the component it is prepared for. If it is published as part of a form addon, and its consumer want to use with a datapicker component, it won't pass down the attributes.

**Question:**

Is there a way to stream down **ALL** the attributes passed to **form-control-group** component?

Maybe the whole concept is wrong, and there is a better pattern to handle this. Any critics and / or ideas are most welcome.

**Edit**

To be clear: in this question: ["setProperties" does not pass "attrs" as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021116/setproperties-does-not-pass-attrs-as-expected) I tried to solve this very problem, passing down the `attrs` hash, which contains all the attributes. Maybe Ember is not ready for this, but I'm sure there is a workaround.